# Is there an equivalent of "extends" in Vue 3 composition API?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, composition, extends

It is possible to extend component when using Options API:

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: "my-comp",
  extends: AnotherComp
```

Is there composition API equivalent?

---

Comment:

I need if for a specific purpose.

Consider extending quasar's Knob component. Original quasar component has props auto-completion:
[image: auto-completion]

However, if I write a wrapper component it will loose auto-completion.

"Extends" allows to preserve auto-completion for parent component's props, but it is a part of Options API.

So, I am looking for a standard way to preserve auto-completion when I use composition API.

Comment: Composition API suggests composition instead of inheritance, as the name suggest. Reused functionality is supposed to be contained in use... functions.

Comment: You could import the other component and use those functions